# How to emulate the default styling of a Lookup column link using JSON column formatting?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I am trying to emulate the `Lookup` column link style in another column using column formatting.

The Lookup column links have a specific color and position within the column cell.

As shown below, I want the links in `My Column` to look like those in `Lookup Column`.

[image]

Using browser developer tools, I can see that there are differences in the HTML of each column:

`Lookup` column link HTML:

```html
<div role="gridcell" aria-readonly="true" aria-colindex="7" class="ms-DetailsRow-cell cell-223 cellUnpadded-111" data-automationid="DetailsRowCell" data-automation-key="LookupColumn" style="width: 190px;">
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="ms-Link od-FieldRender od-FieldRender-lookup root-211" aria-label="My Lookup Value Here" role="link" tabindex="-1">
            My Lookup Value Here
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

`My Column` link HTML:

```html
<div role="gridcell" aria-readonly="true" aria-colindex="8" class="ms-DetailsRow-cell cell-113 cellUnpadded-111" data-automationid="DetailsRowCell" data-automation-key="MyColumn" style="width: 299px;">
    <div class="customField_ab5ae447">
        <div class="sp-field-customFormatter">
            <a style="margin-left:30px;" target="_blank" href="https://some-link-here.com" rel="noopener noreferrer " data-interception="off" tabindex="-1">
        click here to view something
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the JSON I have used to create a link in `My Column`:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "style": {
        "margin-left": "30px"
      },
      "elmType": "a",
      "txtContent": "click here to view something",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "https://some-link-here.com"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I modify the JSON so that the link has the same style as the Lookup column link?

**Edit:**

There is [a similar question here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/299200/custom-view-rowformatter-how-to-make-a-hyperlink-look-like-a-button), but the answers do not produce the same styling as the `Lookup` link column.

Answer (score 0):

through the screenshot I notice the lookup column is also using column formatting. You could edit lookup column using column formatting to see what JSON code are using in it. Then compare which style it is using, such as font, color and so on.

Or, you could provide the JSON code in Lookup Column for further research.

Comment: Hello, It does not appear that the Lookup column has any column formatting applied (when I click on Column header > 'Column settings' > 'Format this column', there is no JSON displayed (even when I click on 'Advanced Mode').  Therefore I cannot view that columns' styling in order to replicate it.  The styling that is applied just seems to be the default styling that is applied to Lookup column links.  And that is what I want to replicate, so that all the links in the list look the same.